# What's the role of string = "" in a program Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i know the title may not be the best, as i'm not exactly how to explain my problem in short words. However i recently was looking at some codes online and i didn't get the reason why some code was used i tried looking on the internet but as i dont know what that part of the code is called ive no idea what to search up so you guys are my last hope.

In this function

```
def NumIntoChar(LineLis):
    for n in LineLis:
        string = ""  # Here is what im not sure. why is this used here ?
        for i in range(n):
            string += '-'
        print(string)
```

Im unsure why string = "" is used between the 2 for looks
another example is:

```
message = """SAHH"""  # Add Code
message = message.upper()
keyShift = 1
encryptedMsg = ""
result = {}

while keyShift <= 26:
    encryptedMsg = ""
    for character in message:
        if character.isalpha() is True:
            x = ord(character) - 65
            x += keyShift
            x = x % 26
            encryptedMsg += chr(x + 65)
        else:
            encryptedMsg += character

    result[keyShift] = encryptedMsg
    keyShift += 1

for r in result.keys():
    print(r,result[r])
```

Here we see ' encryptedMsg = "" ' being used just like in the previous code.

Comment: It initializes an empty string variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just below that line of code, you have this for loop:

```
for i in range(n):
    string += '-'
```

The `x += y` operator is syntactic sugar for `x = x + y`. In order to use this operator, `x` must have a defined value first.

For the first iteration of the loop, `string` will essentially be assigned like this:

```
string = string + '-'
```

In order to avoid `NameError` being thrown, `string` first needs to be declared and assigned some value, which is what `string = ""` does. The expression in the first iteration of the loop then essentially becomes:

```
string = '' + '-'
```

Comment: Thank You dude ! for the simple explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here you initialize a variable with empty string using `var = ''`.

It is commonly followed in scenarios where you have to iteratively concatenate content to form a bigger string. Your code starts with initializing the empty string and within the loop, content of the string is concatenated. For example:

```
 my_str = ""

 while repeat:
     my_str += some_str
     # Do some stuff
```

Other scenario in which you might need it is: when you have to set default value of string as empty, but based on some condition reset the content of string. For example:

```
my_name = ''
if user.is_logged_in():
    my_name = user.name
```

Also read: [Initialize a string variable in Python: “” or None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398164/initialize-a-string-variable-in-python-or-none)